# animated gif image doesn't work on refreshing webpage

Tags: html, animated-gif

I've several animated gif images on a webpage which plays when the page is loaded for the first time. Problem is those gif images doesn't show up as it meant to be when the page is loaded for the second time.May be it's because of browser caching or whatever. And my gif images are not  looped.
any help?

Comment: i found a way arround i just made them to loop..so that now when the page reloads the gif image plays from the beginning..morover i didn't know how to show you guys an example..thanx for the replies

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) is a great way of sharing examples. Also, if you have a solution, please write an answer and accept it – doing so lets other people know that you're no longer looking for an answer :)